# how can I call another activity button click event from fragment

Tags: android

How can I call `activity_share_home.xml` btnGet Click event from `Tab_Apps.java`.

When I call btnGet click event from Tab_Apps.java the app was crash.

Tab_Apps.java

```
public class Tab_Apps extends Fragment implements AppListener {

 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_apps, container, false);
        final ArrayList<ItemList> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();
        Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.anm_btnGet);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                file_sharing.MakeToast("Called");
            }
        });
@Override
    public void onListAction(Boolean isSelected) {
        ((Share_Home)getActivity()).itemSelection(isSelected);
    }
}
```

activity_share_home.xml

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/anm_btnGet"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/gradient_send_button"
   android:text="@string/send"
   android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

Error Message

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: The button will be always *null* as it is not a part of `fragment_tab_apps` layout. You have to access that button where you are setting `activity_share_home` using `setContentView` or `inflating` that layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your **button is referring to null**. Make sure your button is referring to correct id.

Also if you're not using **binding** then you should only inflate and return the view in **onCreateView**.

And do your rest stuff in **onViewCreated** as it makes sure that you get the **inflated view**.

You can use the **Log** to debug your code and check if your **view or button is null or not**.

Answer (score 1):

If your button is located in the activity layout, you should refer to that button and set the listener to that button inside the corresponding **activity** code.

If you then need to call a method that is located inside the fragment, you can either keep a reference to the fragment instance when you create it, or you can get the instance of the current fragment with this method:

```
Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
```

Then for calling a method inside your fragment from your activity, you'll use this reference. So, **in your activity**:

```
Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.anm_btnGet);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                    if (currentFrag instanceof Tab_Apps) {
                       ((Tab_Apps)currentFrag).startFileSharing() //or whatever
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the button is not initialized yet. Move this part to the `OnViewCreated`.

```
Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.anm_btnGet);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            file_sharing.MakeToast("Called");
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the difference between your code and my code,
can you please explain.

Comment: The code is the same, just put it in `onViewCreated` instead of `OnCreateView`

Comment: it was still crash